# How do I implement a dark mode switch on an html page that holds onto its state after reloading and for other connected local html pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently creating a portfolio website using HTML/CSS/JavaScript and I am really struggling to figure out the best way to implement a dark mode button. My current solution uses a separate CSS page that changes the CSS variable values to the dark mode colors when the user switches on dark mode. In order to hold that state, I have a separate JavaScript file that adds a boolean variable to local storage, called dark, and when the user switches it on, the boolean is set to true. When loading the page, the JavaScript checks to see if the boolean variable exists and if it does then set the theme accordingly (if false then keep current theme-style CSS page, if true then use dark.css).

Technically, this works. It does what I want it to do, eventually. At the moment there is a delay when switching to separate pages and when reloading a page. The page first completely loads with the original white themed colors and then checks the local storage and then sets the theme-style and then loads again with the dark theme. Because it goes from a dark theme then flash of white theme and then back to a dark theme it is really annoying and jarring so I would really like to prevent that from happening.

Here is my current JavaScript code:

```
window.onbeforeprint = darkMode();

function darkMode() {
    /*===== Dark Mode =====*/
    let theme = localStorage.getItem('dark');
    let element = document.getElementById("theme-style");

    // Check if state is initialized
    if (theme != null) {
        setTheme(theme);
    }

    // Set the css for the theme-style sheet
    function setTheme(theme) {
        if (theme === "true") {
            element.href = 'assets/css/dark.css';
            document.getElementById("darkmode-toggle").checked = true;
        } else {
            element.href = 'assets/css/styles.css';
            document.getElementById("darkmode-toggle").checked = false;
        }
    }

    // If dark mode is selected
    document.getElementById("darkmode-toggle").onclick = function checkClickFunc() {
        localStorage.setItem('dark', document.getElementById("darkmode-toggle").checked);
        if (document.getElementById("darkmode-toggle").checked) {
            element.href = 'assets/css/dark.css';
        } else {
            element.href = 'assets/css/styles.css';
        }
    }
}
```

I have already tried a number of different solutions online and none have worked so far. I have tried using the "window.onbeforeprint" function, I have tried moving the JavaScript to the head portion of the HTML, and I have tried setting the type to "module" instead of "text/javascript". I am still new to web design and so I don't full know what I am doing so I would appreciate any amount of help. Also if I need to clarify anything please ask!

Edit:
I have decided to go into a different direction for this issue and I have completely revamped how my light mode and dark mode button works. I have switched to using a button rather than a checkbox, and I now do not have a separate CSS page for dark mode and instead it changes the root variables using a darkmode class. However, I am still getting the same error where it loads and flashes the light mode and then switches quickly to dark mode but I feel like maybe it's slightly less noticeable now? Thank you all for your help so far, if there are any other ideas on how to eliminate the error I would be super grateful.

New JavaScript:

```
// check for saved "darkMode" in localStorage
let darkMode = localStorage.getItem("darkMode"); 

const darkModeToggle = document.querySelector("#dark-mode-toggle");

const enableDarkMode = () => {
  // Add the class to the body
  document.body.classList.add("darkmode");
  // Update darkMode in localStorage
  localStorage.setItem("darkMode", "enabled");
}

const disableDarkMode = () => {
  // Remove the class from the body
  document.body.classList.remove("darkmode");
  // Update darkMode in localStorage 
  localStorage.setItem("darkMode", null);
}
 
// If the user already visited and enabled darkMode
// start things off with it on
if (darkMode === "enabled") {
  enableDarkMode();
}

// When someone clicks the button
darkModeToggle.addEventListener("click", () => {
  // get their darkMode setting
  darkMode = localStorage.getItem("darkMode"); 
  
  // if it not current enabled, enable it
  if (darkMode !== "enabled") {
    enableDarkMode();
  // if it has been enabled, turn it off  
  } else {  
    disableDarkMode(); 
  }
});
```

Comment: What is `window.onbeforeprint` for? Isn't it for event that trigger when you print the page?

Comment: @kennarddh Well in the past I have used window.onload function for webgl so I looked up the other event attributes and onbeforeprint was listed as an option that had a definition of "Script to be run before the document is printed" so I thought that might work but it did not for my case. Though maybe I am using it incorrectly?

Comment: But `document is printed` means literal print to paper. Not before browser paint dom event.

Comment: Also, you are assigning the result of the function here `window.onbeforeprint = darkMode();` not the function reference. So `darkMode` is called immediately and then nothing happens when that even occurs

Comment: @Konrad you're right, I don't know why I didn't see that. However, after fixing it, it doesn't solve my problem unfortunately.

Comment: @kennarddh Do you know of a way that I can run the JavaScript code before the body element renders?

Comment: it have a short light mode before the dark.css loaded right?

Comment: Maybe a loading overlay?

Comment: @kennarddh Yeah I forgot to mention that as something that I tried and basically it worked, but I have another main.js file that runs a few other things like a scrolling animation where sections of my website would appear when you looked at them. When I used a loading overlay it essentially loaded the entire page, ran the animations, and then displayed the page. Though it did solve the flashing problem so I am kind of torn between fun animations and dark & light mode features at the moment lol.

Comment: If you put your script in the head it should load before the body loads, but you have to remove references to the toggle button

Comment: Switching between two different stylesheets is not a good approach to this to begin with, IMHO. The _structure_ of your page layout will probably stay mostly identical, and it is basically just colors that are changing (right?) - so this should be handled within _one_ stylesheet. Toggle a class on the body or html element to acivate/deactivate your dark mode.

Comment: I too have the same issue with CSS themes. I haven't attempted it yet but if your script is loaded as type="module" then that is what causes the flash. JS modules are deferred until the HTML has been fully parsed and the initial DOM created.

Comment: @vaughngx4 Well unfortunately I was having the issue before I switched to type "module" and doing so made no difference.